# Auto selecting a row in kendo grid

Tags: grid, kendo-ui

I have a kendo grid in which a details grid is created for each row when clicked on a row.

Each row in the main grid have a column e.g. LifeTimeId of the user.

When the grid is loaded is there a way to autoselect a row in the grid with a particular LifeTimeId?

I was trying the following logic in 'dataBound'event:

```js
function () 
{
    var e1 = $("grid");
    var grid = e1.data("kendoGrid");
    var row = grid.table.find('tr[data-LifeTimeNumber="T006"]')
    grid.select(row);
}
```

I was hoping that this would fire a change event of the grid.
In the change event I have the logic to retrieve other data from this selected row and do some business logic.

This approach never worked however as the above code in dataBound event failed to select the row.

Any clues on what could be done to solve this problem of auto selecting a particular row in the grid when it loads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `expandRow` method in the function you have at dataBound.

E.g.

```js
function () 
{
    var e1 = $("grid");
    var grid = e1.data("kendoGrid");
    var row = grid.table.find('tr[data-LifeTimeNumber="T006"]');
    this.expandRow(row);
}
```

I created a example here: http://jsfiddle.net/amomsen/6GgAu/6/

See more on expand row: 
http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#methods-expandRow

Answer (score 0):

You can try running your function in a setTimeout right after initializing the grid.
Works for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
var row = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid").table.find('tr[data-uid='+uid+']');
$(row).addClass('k-state-selected');
```

Adding class to particular row in dataBound event will work what you want.

Comment: there's an explicit API method (grid.select()), so relying on a specific class (which may change in future releases) may not be the best idea